# What is the best practice when an web application server is restarting and show a page that the server is in construction

Tags: domain-name-system

I'd like to restart my server and want to show clients that the website is under construction or something.

What I can think of is that

Change DNS setting to another server which has an html page like under construction before restarting the server and then when the server successfully restarted I change the DNS setting back to my server.

But This case has a possibility that the DNS change might take a few hours.

Is there a best practice to show a certain page to clients while my server is restarting?

Comment: I guess you could virtualize your server into two or more servers, maybe three including a load balancer, then reboot one virtual server at a time. DNS won't work, it's too slow, as you said. I wonder if having two A records would work, but again that's two servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to restart my server and want to show clients that the website is under construction <during reboot>

While your server is rebooting it can't respond to queries, but typically that is something that only takes a couple of minutes at worst, which for small web sites is not a very big issue, especially when you **schedule maintenance outside of peak hours.**

If that is a big issue, then you should either manage expectations or you should not host your web site on a single server.

When you can't afford a little downtime every now and then for scheduled maintenance, you need a minimum *something* to remain online to at least display the maintenance notification.  That probably means you have both the business case and the need for a highly available infrastructure and application design (think a pair of load balancers with a floating/shared IP address between them, multiple back-end web servers and an HA database and data storage design), which allows individual components/servers to either fail or be scheduled for maintenance without interrupting your service.

That requires more expertise to both set up and maintain, will cost much more (and is arguably still fragile and likely to fail catastrophically if that is not your core competence).

Comment: I think we should afford downtime for a few seconds because of the cost of maintaining two servers and maybe a load balancer. Thanks for the best practice! I will implement this case when we cannot afford a little bit of downtime.